# Javascript - Finding if there is an integer in a string

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split, parseint

I appreciate this is very basic. Please go easy on me, I am at the beginning of my coding journey!

I am trying to establish whether there is an integer anywhere in a string. If there is, it should return true. If not, it should return false.

Here is my code, which is failing as it is returning true even when there are no integers present. I cannot work out why this might be happening.

```
function findTicketPrices(emailString) {
    let emailArray = emailString.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {
        if (typeof parseInt(emailArray[i]) === "number") {
            return true;
        }
        return false
    } 
}
```

Comment: so just use a regular expression

Comment: `parseInt` returns `NaN` when given an invalid argument. Despite its name, `NaN` is, in fact, of type number. Try changing your `if` statement to instead check if the result is `NaN`, rather than seeing if the type is number. For this, the `Number.isNaN()` function will help you.

Answer (score 4):

So couple issues:

1. Parsing a string into a number, if it fails it returns NaN, and typeof NaN is still a number
2. You are returning false inside of the loop, so it exits in the first iteration no matter what.

```
function findTicketPrices(emailString) {
  let emailArray = emailString.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {
    const value = parseInt(emailArray[i]);
    if (typeof value === "number" && !isNaN(value)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks good except I think you'd need `.split('')`, i.e., no single space but rather blank string/space instead.

Comment: I originally considered that, but what if OP did it for a reason? Like accounting for a value where there is a number and a letter in the argument. `hello 7d 77` would result in `7d` being a false positive.
I understand that it's supposed to be an email? but still worth considering.

Comment: Might just be a string of emails separated by spaces.

Comment: But will an email have any blanks to split on? Also, you can just index lookup a character in a string. No need to turn into an array first.

Comment: Just index the string and don't worry about splitting into an array.

Comment: Even if email has blank spaces, your array will split only on those, and will therefore be incorrect.

Comment: Also with `!isNaN(value)` you don't need the `typeof` check.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt(emailArray[i])` always returns a number so `typeof parseInt(emailArray[i])` will always be `number`

I would use `Number.isNaN` to check if `parseInt` returned `NaN` which indicates that it's not a number

Also, you are returning too fast with that `return false`

```js
function findTicketPrices(emailString) {
    let emailArray = emailString.split("");
    for (let i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {
        if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(emailArray[i]))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false
}

const emails = ['abd1das2@stackoverflow.com', 'abdfdass@stackoverflow.com']

for (const email of emails) {
  console.log(email, findTicketPrices(email))
}
```

You can also do it easier with regex

```js
function findTicketPrices(emailString) {
  return Boolean(emailString.match(/\d/g))
}

const emails = ['abd1das2@stackoverflow.com', 'abdfdass@stackoverflow.com']

for (const email of emails) {
  console.log(email, findTicketPrices(email))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are splitting on spaces and not the characters. It should be

```js
const emailArray = emailString.split("");
```

Your check fails because `parseInt('a')` returns NaN. And NaN is a number.

```js
console.log(typeof NaN)
```

If you want to check for a number, it is just a simple reg exp

```js
var str = 'aaaa1bbbbb';
var numRE = /\d/;
console.log(numRE.test(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you could convert the string to a list of characters, and then loop through that list, and for each character check if it's an integer. To do that you'd use the built in `parseInt` function and see if passing the current character into this function returns NaN. That can be checked using the built in `isNaN` function. The following code does this on one line

```
const findTicketPrices = emailString => emailString.toString().split("").find(c => !isNaN(parseInt(c))) !== undefined
```

If you don't want to do this on one line, this code will also do the trick

```
const findTicketPrices = emailString => {
    const emailArray = emailString.toString().split("");
    for(const i in emailArray){
    const character = emailArray[i];
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(character))){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need (just index lookup in the string):

```
function findTicketPrices(emailString) {
  for (let i = 0; i < emailString.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(emailString[i]))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
const containsInteger = str => /\d/.test(str)
```